# How can I use a UWP Class Library for scripting?

Tags: scripting, uwp, windows-10

I have a UWP Class Library project (written in C#) with some useful utility classes and functions. I want to create a script that uses these classes and functions and runs a few times a day automatically. What is the best way to achieve this?

Should I create an app? If so how can I make it run a few times a day?

Should I create a classic console exe program and run it using a script? If yes, can console apps use UWP class libraries?

Should I create a Windows Runtime Component with background task?

Or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're definition of "scripting" can be stretched to mean "run an app" there's lots you can do. If you want something that will be seen as a more traditional script then the best you can do is compile the code in a standard .Net class library (not a UWP one) and then call it from a PowerShell script. If you can run apps then there are a few options and the most appropriate will probably depend on the device they're running on, how often you want them to run, and what they actually do.

As you're talking about a UWP app we should allow for it running on different "device families". The easiest way to run on different devices (desktop & phone, etc.) is to have a periodic background task. At time intervals defined by you it will try and run. Subject to connectivity, power, etc.

Because you said a console app was an option then you're probably really only interested in a desktop/PC environment. That's where there's the most options.

Firstly, if your code uses UWP/Win10 specific APIs then compiling into a console app probably isn't possible without changing the code.  I do many things like you describe in the question and use console apps for this as I find them the simplest to work with.

If you're going to change code, consider moving to using Portable Class Libraries as you'll then be able to link to that code from many different types of app--including traditional desktop and UWP apps.

I'd avoid creating a runtime component unless you really need to as there are lots of potential gotchas.

You can run any app from the Task Scheduler but launching UWP apps is tricky.

You can launch a regular app or script by setting the action of the task to be the exe. (or the exe and passing the script file as a parameter.)

Apps from the store don't have an EXE you can just launch so you need to do a bit more. They can only be launched by the Windows Shell. But, fortunately, there's a way to do this. Have your task start explorer.exe (You'll find it in C:\Windows) and then add the argument `shell:AppsFolder\[app-PFN]!App`.
Where `[app-PFN]` is the Product Family Name of the app. You can find the values of all the installed apps on your machine by looking at "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\"

So, you can use this to launch the store app.

```
shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

[image: Task Scheduler app showing the actions tab including above example]